# Kotlin adapter remove item

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I'm trying to have item removed from my list but I get following error

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline fun <T> MutableCollection<out TypeVariable(T)>.remove(element: TypeVariable(T)): Boolean defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <T> MutableList<TypeVariable(T)>.remove(index: Int): TypeVariable(T) defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> MutableMap<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.remove(key: TypeVariable(K)): TypeVariable(V)? defined in kotlin.collections
```

`Code`

```
class EducationsAdapter(val context: Context?, private var educationList: MyEducations) : RecyclerView.Adapter<EducationsAdapter.EducationsAdapterViewHolder>() {

  override fun getItemCount()= educationList.data.size
  // other functions...


  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EducationsAdapter.EducationsAdapterViewHolder, position: Int) 
  {
    holder.educationDelete.setOnClickListener {
      deleteMyEducations(currentItem.id, position)
    }
  }
  
  //delete  
  private fun deleteMyEducations(id: String, position: Int) {
    // ".remove" is returning error above
    educationList.remove(position)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }

}
```

**Any suggestions?**

## Update

My `MyEducations` class (rendering data coming from server)

```
data class MyEducations(
    val data: List<Education>,
    val message: String
) { }

data class Education(
    val id: String,
    val start: String,
    val end: String,
    val title: String,
    val body: String,
    val user: User,
    val created_at: String,
    val updated_at: String,
) {}
```

## Update 2

I've made following changes

```
// add
val list = mutableListOf<MyEducations>()


private fun deleteMyEducations(id: String, position: Int) {
  //changed to
  list.remove(educationList.data[position])
  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

What it does is make flashing remove of the item (**meaning**: for less than a second my item removes and back again to the list)!

Comment: What is the type of MyEducations? Is it Mutable? If not create it as MutableList and use remove.

Comment: `val data: List<Education>` is non mutable type. Please try `val data: MutableList<Education>`

Comment: @mangupt `Property must be initialized or be abstract` would you mind post an answer? I might be placing it in wrong place!

Comment: Change type of list to `MutableList` or `ArrayList`. On a side note Your adapter should be only interested in `List<Education>` not  in `MyEducations` . `MyEducations` here is just a wrapper class you are using its better if you do not pass it to adapter just pass `myEducations.data` to adapter then remove the Item from list .

Comment: @ADM I did what you suggest still getting `removeAt()` red.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solved

```
//changed my list to `ArrayList<Education>`
class EducationsAdapter(val context: Context?, private var educationList: ArrayList<Education>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<EducationsAdapter.EducationsAdapterViewHolder>() {

  // and my delete code to
  private fun deleteMyEducations(id: String, position: Int) {
    educationList.removeAt(position)
    notifyItemRemoved(position)
    notifyItemRangeChanged(position, educationList.size)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }
}
```

Also I had to change my class to `ArrayList` as well

```
data class MyEducations(
    val data: ArrayList<Education>,
    val message: String
) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try With

```
val list = mutableListOf<MyEducations>()

private fun deleteMyEducations(id: String, position: Int) {
  list.removeAt(position)
  notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to delete with something like:

```
class EducationListAdapter: RecyclerView.Adapter<EducationListAdapter.EducationViewHolder>() {
    var educationList: MutableList<Education> = mutableListOf()

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: EducationViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = educationList.toList()
        holder.view.setOnClickListener {
            educationList.remove(current[position])
            notifyItemRemoved(position)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You cannot remove `, private var educationList: MyEducations` from my adapter it receives data from my API call in fragment. PS: please see my `update 2`

Comment: @mafortis, please accept answer if this works for you.

Comment: @mafortis, my sample snippet was to tell how to use mutablelist.